# UIView: Right Frame - Wrong Position in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

i am facing a strange problem while adding some `UIView`s to my `UIScrollView`.
I calculate the frame of the View correctly and then i add the view to the scrollview.

The first one is well positioned, the second one is overlaying the first one.

I have logged the frame of the views but seems to be ok

VIEW NAME: Members
 VIEW FRAME: {{0, 0}, {768, 258}}
 NEW FRAME: {{0, 159}, {768, 258}}

VIEW NAME: My comment
 VIEW FRAME: {{0, 0}, {768, 50}}
 NEW FRAME: {{0, 420}, {768, 50}}

How can i solve??

```
NSInteger numberOfSections = [self.collapserSections count];

for (int index = 0; index < numberOfSections; index++)
{
    CustomCollapser *collapser = [self.collapserSections objectAtIndex:index];
    collapser.collapserIdentifier = index;
    UIView *controllerView = collapser.configuration.linkedController.view;

    if (collapser.configuration.willRemoveHeader)
    {
        totalHeight = totalHeight + controllerView.frame.size.height;
    }
    else
    {
        if(collapser.collapsed)
        {
            totalHeight = totalHeight + 50;
        }
        else
        {
            totalHeight = totalHeight + collapser.view.frame.size.height;
        }
    }

    switch (index)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            startY = 0;
        }

        break;

        default:
        {
            startY = startY + collapser.configuration.spaceFromThePreviousCollapser;
        }

        break;
    }

    if(collapser.collapsed)
    {
        [collapser.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                            startY,
                                            collapser.view.frame.size.width,
                                            50)];
    }
    else
    {
        [collapser.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                            startY,
                                            collapser.view.frame.size.width,
                                            collapser.view.frame.size.height)];
    }

    if(collapser.configuration.willRemoveHeader)
    {
        startY = startY + controllerView.frame.size.height - 50;
    }
    else
    {
        startY = startY + collapser.view.frame.size.height;
    }

    [self addSubview:collapser.view];
}
```

This is how i load the views to my scrollview

Thank you

Comment: You have to post some code to get helped. We don't know what "members" is or "my comment" is.

Comment: what is the frame and size of UIScrollView object?

Comment: "members" and "my comment" are simply UIView. The ScrollView have bigger size than the two views. The width is 768 and the height is 900

Comment: @user3274912 are you creating members and my comment programatically or through xib?

Comment: I create the two views using XIB and change the size programmatically based on the view content